# Black screen capture from /dev/graphics/fb0 on Android emulator with -gpu on option

Tags: android, android-emulator, framebuffer

I'm trying to generate bitmap image from /dev/graphics/fb0 on Android emulator and it succeeded.

But when I add "-gpu on" option when launch it, it always generate black image.

My code is from here

http://www.pocketmagic.net/android-native-screen-capture-application-using-the-framebuffer/

Without the option, the emulator is too slow for my purpose.

Is there any way to get a screen capture from /dev/graphics/fb0 with -gpu on option?

To avoid unnecessary IO, I don't want to use /syste/bin/screencap.

Thanks for all helps!

Comment: Since you are trying to do something like adb screenrecord see http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/106060/adb-android-emulator-unable-to-record-video-screenrecord-not-found-with-an and specifically this bug tracker: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61682. As your question(s) involve image processing - have you reviewed: https://github.com/google/grafika and http://www.bigflake.com/mediacodec/

Comment: Thanks for giving a comment! I will track the bug remaining on emulator.